# объясните пожалуйста разницу между justify-content: center и margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css, figma

Я новичок в верстке пока не понимаю как работает центрирование элементов. Если я правильно поняла,  margin: 0 auto- для центрирования элемента фиксированной ширины внутри родительского контейнера. Но тогда я не понимаю что делает justify-content :center. Может кто-то сможет объяснить почему где-то нужно использовать и то и другое.

Comment: `justify-content: center;` работает только для `flex` элементов. И если у вас в нём нет необходимости, то можете выровнять за счёт `margin: 0 auto;` Каждый сам решает что ему нужно.  И, если кому-то *"где-то нужно использовать и то и другое"*, то приводите конкретный пример, а не заставляйте нас угадывать кому и зачем это нужно.

Comment: @stylok, может оставите ответ как ответ, а не комментарий?

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: center;` работает только для `flex` элементов. И если у вас в нём нет необходимости, то можете выровнять за счёт `margin: 0 auto;` Каждый сам решает что ему нужно. И, если кому-то *"где-то нужно использовать и то и другое"*, то приведите конкретный пример, а не заставляйте нас угадывать кому и зачем это нужно.